# Unable to add email in Gmail "send email as" using Postfix

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-16.04

I've the default Postfix installation and I want to be able to send email as `contactus@accountrecovery.in` thru Google.

With sites hosted on Ubuntu 12 and 14 I've been successfully using since long time.

Now when I try to add this email in the gmail using different settings(Port, SSL/TLS etc)  in this Ubuntu 16.4 I see these lines in the `/var/log/mail.log`:

```
Jul  8 21:19:35 host postfix/smtpd[15433]: connect from mail-lj1-f180.google.com[209.85.208.180]
Jul  8 21:19:37 host postfix/smtpd[15433]: lost connection after EHLO from mail-lj1-f180.google.com[209.85.208.180]
Jul  8 21:19:37 host postfix/smtpd[15433]: disconnect from mail-lj1-f180.google.com[209.85.208.180] ehlo=2 starttls=1 commands=3
```

### main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = host.digitaltransactions.in
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
virtual_alias_domains = accountrecovery.in
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

inet_protocols = ipv4
```

[image]

Comment: As the error indicates, Google can't authenticate with TLS on port 25, you need to set up (SASL) authentication in Postfix on your mailserver. Your config does not show any of the needed `smtpd_sasl*` options required for that. See: http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html . Also: using a self signed certificates (`smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem`) is not recommended

Comment: You need to define how postfix authenticates a user, see my answer on this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281299/how-to-configure-my-postfix-to-use-outlook-thunderbird#51412334